# Rename all other levels to "Other"

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing all the calls that I have done in the last year. Under the column "Name" there are the names of the people in my contact list. In R this column contains 30 factors, I want to have only 3 factors: *Mom*, *Dad*, *BestFriend* and **Others**.
I'm using this snippet:

`library(plyr)
call$Name <- mapvalues(call$Name, from = 'Mikey Mouse', to = 'BFF')
call$Name <- mapvalues(call$Name, from = c('Rocky Balboa','Uma Thurman'), to = c('Dad','Mom'))`

How can I rename all other levels aside those 3 to **Other**?

Comment: As a side note, why use 2 `mapvalues` calls? You can clearly specify multiple `from=` and `to=`, so why not put them all in the one call?

Comment: See `?factor`. Specifically, `levels` and `labels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can first create a `level` 'Others' (assuming it is a `factor`), assign the `levels` that are not `%in%` the vector of `levels` ('nm1') to 'Other'

```
levels(call$Name) <- c(levels(call$Name), 'Other'))
levels(call$Name)[!levels(call$Name %in% nm1] <- 'Other'
```

---

Or another option is `recode` from `dplyr` which also have the `.default` option to specify other levels that are not in the vector to a given value

```
library(dplyr)
recode(call$Name, `Mikey Mouse` =  'BFF', `Rocky Balboa` = 'Dad',
    `Uma Thurman` = 'Mom', .default = 'Other')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
call <- data.frame(Name = sample(c('Mikey Mouse', 'Rocky Balboa',
  'Uma Thurman', 'Richard Gere', 'Rick Perry'), 25, replace = TRUE))
nm1 <- c('Mickey Mouse', 'Rocky Balboa', 'Uma Thurman')
```

Comment: the compiler says `Error in !levels(call$Name %in% nm1) : invalid argument type`

Comment: @GiuseppeMinardi  Here, I am assuming that you have a `factor` column (as you mentioned `levels`).  Please check the `class(call$Name)`.  If it is `character`, you can directly do this without any `levels`

Comment: This is a factor columns, but the script you proposed doesnt work, this snippes works: `nm1 <- c('BFF','Dad','Mom')
levels(call$Name) <- c(levels(call$Name), 'Other')
call$Name[!(call$Name %in% nm1)] <- 'Other'`

Comment: @GiuseppeMinardi  Ok, I think you have already changed the values from 'Mickey Mouse' to 'BFF' with the `mapvalues` script. I was thinking about using this initially

Comment: This way, you are resetting all the _levels_ to "Other", which is not the same as setting all values to the same level ("Other").
I think you want a simpler `call$Name[!call$Name %in% nm1] <- 'Other'`, after your first line, eventually followed by `call$Name <- droplevels(call$Name)`

Comment: @EmilBode  As I said earlier, I am assuming it as a `factor` column.  Your method won't work with `factor` column.  Also, I didn't set all levels to `Other`.  I am adding a new level before doing the assignment

Comment: @EmilBode  With a small example `v1 <- factor(c('a', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'f'));levels(v1) <- c(levels(v1), 'Other'); levels(v1)[!levels(v1) %in% c('a', 'b')] <- 'Other';
 v1
#[1] a     b     a     Other Other
Levels: a b Other`

Comment: @akrun: You're right that apparently R removes all duplicate levels, I didn't expect that. But my example said "after your first line", and then my code still works. 
What you're doing is resetting all the levels, what I am doing is after you've created the extra level, resetting all values to that level.
Actually, in your approach the first step is not neccessary, while it is with my code.

Comment: @EmilBode  Thanks. Got it. I understand your point.  But, if the data is really big and have few `levels`. then changing it with `levels` would be faster

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `fct_other()` function in the `forcats` package for doing exactly this. Using the data akrun provided we could simply do:

```
library(forcats)

call$Name <- fct_other(call$Name, keep = nm1)
```